# Animated loading gif with iframes loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, loading

I have this little script which displays a loading animated gif (throbber wheel) whilst my iframe is loading and then disappears when it fully loads:

```
 $('#mainiframe').load(function() {
    $("#loadani").addClass("nodisplay");
 });
```

This works great. But I was wondering if anyone knew a way to adapt this so that it works whenever a new page loads within the iframe (eg: if a user clicks a link within the iframe and navigates to a new page)?

Any advice would be great! Thanks

Comment: do you own the page inside the iframe? you'd have to do child to parent frame communication

Comment: does the iframe have the same domain protocol and port as the parent document?

Comment: @AndyRay and no the iframe is on a seperate domain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I was wondering if anyone knew a way to adapt this so that it
>   works whenever a new page loads within the iframe

If you don't own the iframe, then no. You can spottily detect the load event of pages in a new browser, but that only happens after the page is loaded.